# Looking for an Algorithm for getting Polygons in List of open Pathes(Lists of Vector2d )

Tags: c#, graphics, polygon, intersection

i´m wondering if there is an algorithm to all get the closed Polygons in a set of Pathes, like in the Image. I know there is the Intersection algorithm and als intesection of two closed Polygons, but I have just these vector of lines as an input. I´m working in C# and Unity. But of course this is a general question.
Thanks ahead[image: []

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

1. Intersect each polyline with all others.
2. Split each polyline at the intersection points. Creating separate segments between each intersection point.
3. Put each segment in a structure representing a graph, with a node at each intersection, and edges to describe how nodes are connected.
4. Start any arbitrary segment
5. Traverse the graph, selecting the first clockwise edge at each node.
6. When the starting edge is reached, Output the traversed polygon
7. Mark each traversed edge.
8. Repeat from step 5, selecting the next un-marked edge.

There are multiple ways to describe a graph in this way. I would suggest using half-edge structure, where each edge is stored two times, in opposite directions. So the nodes would have a list of outgoing edges, and each edge would have a single target node. This makes it easier to mark traversed edges since you do not need to keep track of the direction you are traveling in.